# Start Applet not initialized Asteroids Game

Tags: java, netbeans, 2d-games

I am learning Java and figured the best way is through a mix of QnA, Practice books, Game Programming and Apps on my phone.  So far it has been successful but...

In one of the game programming books it has me make a java applet that creates an asteroids game.  I am using NetBeans and when I run the file an applet window opens, blank, and at the bottom it says Start: Applet not initialized.

In the book it has this as the initializing event:

```
//Primary class for the game
public abstract class Asteroids extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener 
{

    //The Main thread becomes the game loop

    Thread gameloop;

    //Use this as a double buffer
    BufferedImage backbuffer;

    //The Main drawing object for the back buffer
    Graphics2D g2d;

    //toggle for drawing bounding boxes
    boolean showBounds = false;

    //create the asteroid array
    int ASTEROIDS = 20;
    Asteroid[] ast = new Asteroid[ASTEROIDS];

    //Create the bullet Array
    int BULLETS = 10;
    Bullet[] bullet = new Bullet[BULLETS];
    int currentBullet = 0;

    //The Players Ship
    Ship ship = new Ship();

    //Create the Identity transform(0,0)
    AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();

    //Create a random number generator
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Applet init event
    public void init() 
    {
        //Create the back buffer for smooth graphics
        backbuffer = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g2d = backbuffer.createGraphics();

        //Set Up the Ship!
        ship.setX(320);
        ship.setY(240);

        //Set the Bullets up!
        for (int n = 0; n < BULLETS; n++) 
        {
            bullet[n] = new Bullet();
        }

        //Creating Asteroids!
        for (int n = 0; n < ASTEROIDS; n++) 
        {
            ast[n] = new Asteroid();
            ast[n].setRotationVelocity(rand.nextInt(3) + 1);
            ast[n].setX((double) rand.nextInt(600) + 20);
            ast[n].setY((double) rand.nextInt(440) + 20);
            ast[n].setMoveAngle(rand.nextInt(360));
            double ang = ast[n].getMoveAngle() - 90;
            ast[n].setVelX(calcAngleMoveX(ang));
            ast[n].setVelY(calcAngleMoveY(ang));
        }
        //Start User Input Listener
        addKeyListener(this);
```

That is what it says SHOULD start the applet.

I don't know if this is all that is needed but there is alot more.  I have checked, double checked and triple checked the code and it is correct.

Comment: No, it's not all that is needed. Create and post an [mcve].

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Oh, and applets are basically deprecated, since pretty much no browser will actively load them any more.  They are also alot of trouble when you're just learning, you're much better off just using a `JPanel` as a starting point and adding that to a instance of a `JFrame`.  Swing components are also double buffered by default, which means you can do away with needing a `BufferedImage` ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your help.  In future chapters of this book, "Beginning Java Game Programming," they get more into JPanel and JFrame, but as a beginning tutorial they have a smaller game using 5 classes.

Comment: The class is declared as abstract, Java can't initialise abstract classes

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you.  When I removed the abstract it red underlines Asteroids and when I Alt+Enter it says "Make Class Asteroids Abstract"  Asteroids is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyPressed(KeyEvent) in KeyListener.  And Missing Javadoc.

Comment: Then you need to implement the contractual requirements of the `KeyListener`, see [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: I am using the `case KeyEvent.VK_` left, right, up, and space. and `addKeyListener(this)`  and `//Key listener events
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) 
    {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) 
    {
    }

    public void keyPress(KeyEvent k) 
    {
        int keyCode = k.getKeyCode();`